# What is the best way to build the GNU Scientific Library for use on MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, gsl

I'm trying to get GSL version 1.16 built using MinGW but I'm running into some problems. I followed [these instructions](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~daneel/GSL_devcpp.html#updates#2) which involve invoking these commands from within sh.exe.

```
tar zxvf <the name of your gsl source package>
cd gsl-<the version number of your gsl source package>
./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=yes --prefix=/c/GSL-<version number of gsl source package>
make
make install
```

I obtained these messages before `make` gave up.

```
/usr/bin/sed: can't read <my last name>/gsl-1.16/cblas/libgslcblas.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `<my last name>/gsl-1.16/cblas/libgslcblas.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [libgsl.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/<my full name>/gsl-1.16'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/home/<my full name>/gsl-1.16'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone explain this? Could it be something to do with one of the file paths involving a space between my first last names? Alternatively, does anyone know of me another way to install the GSL which has definitely worked for them?

Comment: _"Could it be something to do with one of the file paths involving a space between my first last names?"_ This could well be a reason. Try using another account without spaces in the account name, to compile and install.

Comment: BTW why did you tag [tag:linux]? [tag:mingw] implies [tag:windows] IIRC.